# How to manage sub-domains on WinHost with IIS7 URL Rewrite 2.0?

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I'm trying out [WinHost](http://www.winhost.com/) and I'm running into some issues with sub-domains. On WinHost, you can have multiple sub-domains per hosting account, but each sub-domain points to the root website. E.g. you can have www.example.com, sub1.example.com, and sub2.example.com but all of them display the content at http://www.example.com/.

Other Hosts allow you to point sub-domains to a sub folder in your website. This would allow you to point sub1.example.com to /sub1, sub2.example.com to /sub2 and www.example.com to /.

WinHost recommends using an [asp/aspx page](http://support.winhost.com/KB/a649/how-to-redirect-a-subdomain-to-a-subdirectory.aspx) to redirect http://sub1.example.com to http://sub1.example.com/sub1, which points to /sub1. While that would work, I'd like to not have the subdomain in the url twice.

So I tried using IIS7 URL Rewrite to point http://sub1.example.com to /sub1. Ben Powell describes this in detail on [his blog](http://blog.benpowell.co.uk/2010/02/winhostcom-how-to-really-run-multiple.html). This is great, except Request.ApplicationPath is now /sub1/path/to/current/page.aspx, which breaks ASP.Net Themes (and probably other stuff too).

What can I do to fix the ApplicationPath? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to fix the application path, so now I'm simply using the URL Rewrite Module to redirect (not rewrite) from `http://sub.example.com/abc` to `http://sub.example.com/sub/abc`. It's not ideal, but it works. See my [blog post](https://jrummell.com/winhost-sub-domains-and-iis-7-url-rewrite) for the details.

Comment: Thanks for this blog. I've been struggling with the same issue ever since WH4L sold-out and moved to a new platform offering less features than before so I was looking at WinHost. I'd ended up at the URL rewrite workaround for this but like you, I'm struggling to get Response.Redirect("~/MyPage.aspx") working

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the redirect, you will need to mark each site as an application in IIS.  WinHost should have a control panel or way for you to mark each of the sites as their own application.  That will make folders like /sub1/ as a root application.

Comment: Yes, /sub1 is an application root but it doesn't help the ApplicationPath problem. For the time being, I changed the rule to redirect to http://sub1.example.com/sub1 instead of rewriting it. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: I'm not positive of the syntax right off but it's something like Request.ApplicationPath("~\") that will give you the path relative to the root of the application that you're currently in.